# Google's android products are still going to phone storage

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, gmail, google-hangouts

I have changed my android device's default app storage as memory card using adb shell command. It is working fine for most android apps. But when download and install apps that google such as Hangouts, Gmail, etc. They go to phone storage. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many apps require to be stored in internal storage. This is by design and it cannot be changed. Most of the Google apps such as Hangouts and GMail cannot be stored to external storage (i.e. SD Card). So whenever you download an app that requires internal storage it will be stored in internal storage regardless of your app storage setting.

P.S. Developers prefer internal storage as external storage is generally slow to read and affects the performance negatively.